# How to stop 2 times data fetch in SSR (first on server side and then on client side)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, server-side-rendering

I am implementing **Server side rendering** to a **react and redux SPA application** . So for SSR I **fetch data on server** and make page by using renderToString method and then on **client side I fetch data in useEffect** as shown in below example.

Now issue is that after fetching data  on server, client is again calling  **fetchRequestQuery(dispatch)** in useEffect. so it is calling same API 2 times which is wrong. I can't remove useEffect as when I navigate page(react router Link) then data should be fetch on client side only for SPA.

So how could I disable api call in useEffect on client side when open page first time but when we navigate page then it should be working normal and make API call in useEffect?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchRequestQuery } from '../actions';

const loadData = dispatch => (
  fetchRequestQuery(dispatch)
);

const Content = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    loadData(dispatch);
  }, []);

  const { request } = useSelector(state => state);
  return (
    <span>{JSON.stringify(request)}</span>
  );
};

export default {
  component: Content,
  loadData,
};
```

```
import { matchRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import Routes from './Routes';
import renderer from './helpers/renderer';
import createStore from './store';

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const store = createStore();
  const { dispatch } = store;
  const routes = matchRoutes(Routes, req.path);
  const promises = routes.map(
    ({ route }) => (route.loadData ? route.loadData(dispatch) : null),
  );
  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    const content = renderer(req, store);
    res.send(content);
  });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: About your question about disable... You can't do that. But, I think you should add a condition in your useEffect. Maybe you can use a prop inside Content... I don't know but it would be easy if you use a variable and a condition

Comment: In angular we can use the `ServerTransferStateModule` for this. Don't know for react, but I can imagine that something similar will exist... It basically lets you record whatever you want to transfer in an object that's being serialized and append to the html, so that you can access it from client javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a variable and set it to true when your component render on client only and , if this variable  is true your data while be fetched something like this:

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchRequestQuery } from '../actions';

const loadData = dispatch => (
  fetchRequestQuery(dispatch)
);

const Content = () => {
  const initial = useRef(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if(window && initial.current){
        // this should run in second render on client
        loadData(dispatch);
    } else if(window) {
        // this should run in first render on client
        initial.current = true;
    } else{
        // this should run on server side
        loadData(dispatch);
    }
  }, []);

  const { request } = useSelector(state => state);
  return (
    <span>{JSON.stringify(request)}</span>
  );
};

export default {
  component: Content,
  loadData,
};
```

Comment: Will the `initial` ref be in all of the components?